# android pair command not found ( Wireless Debugging )

Tags: android, adb, adbwireless

I am trying to connect to my phone wirelessly for USB Debugging using following :

`adb pair 192.168.30.27:41424` .

But I am getting following error:

`"Unknown command pair" error.`

I have already updated Android SDK Platform tools to 31+ version, still this does not fix this issue.

Comment: You most likely did not update SDK platform tools to recent version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar issues. Uninstalling and installing **Android SDK Platform-Tools** solved the problem. Please make sure that the "Android SDK Platform-Tools" version is at least 30 or above.

Comment: I have `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32` where can I see if it is below or higher than version 30?

Comment: i have 1.0.40 but still not working

Comment: @famfamfam Check if your CLI is pointing to the right adb with `which adb` or `where adb` to see where its pointing.

Comment: this would appear to be a windows specific solution, perhaps even Visual Studio?

Answer (score 8):

Prior to Android 11, the command to connect ADB over WiFi was:

```bash
adb connect 192.168.30.27
```

Not `pair`.
Also, no code was needed.

Note, that you must first connect your device over USB and run:

```bash
adb tcpip 5555
```

To turn ADB over WiFi on.

Note, that to use the new `pair` command, your device must it self be running Android 11+, if it has an older OS, the SDK version on your PC will not matter.

Comment: I am aware of this and this requires usb cable at least 1 time. For me uninstalling/installing platform tools helped fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you updated recently then even though the update is on your system, you might have an older version of the adb server running. So try:

`adb kill-server`

and then `adb pair` again. Found this here: [ADB pair unknown command using r32 platform tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886665/adb-pair-unknown-command-using-r32-platform-tools#comment125326493_70886665)

For me, `adb pair` still didn't work but the "pair devices over wifi" option in Android Studio did, after running that kill-server command.

Answer (score 2):

I see this when running `adb version`:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.6-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

but still getting `adb: unknown command pair` when running `adb pair`

Answer (score 2):

There are two version for adb: the **SDK platform tools** version and the **ADB** version.

For my debian bullseye:

```
~ $ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
```

The second one should be the sdk version.

In google's SDK release note, the wifi pairing feature is published in [v30.0.0](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools#3000_april_2020).

Debian's adb is in sdk version 28, so it does not support wireless pair.

### platform tools binary from google

However, I do not know that what does the adb's own version meaning, but it seem to be stand alone with sdk version.

I download the google's platform tools binary, and it show a different sdk version but a same adb version:

```
~/Downloads/platform-tools $ ./adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.1-9680074
```

Therefore, it need a newer sdk version to use the pair command.

Answer (score 1):

Check your adb version using `adb --version`

With `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40` you get this error.
With `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41`, `adb pair` works!

Update `adb` via Android Studio
(https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where I had multiple installations of platform-tools. Specifically, I had one in /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb and another one in $HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools. The second installation was the updated version, and I had added it to my .bashrc file as follows:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Despite this configuration, the adb version command was still showing the older version:

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

To resolve this, I removed the older version by running:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/
```

After removing the old version, my system started using the latest one, and the adb command began functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Linux Mint), `apt remove` and `apt install` again did not solve the issue.

Downloading platform-tools from the oficial source worked:

> https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools

Unzip, cd to the path, and execute adb there