# ADB pair unknown command using r32 platform tools

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I've just downloaded a fresh install of SDK platform tools since I don't need the IDE.
Version: r32.0.0

When using adb pair i get the following:

```
PS C:\*userpath*\platform-tools_r32.0.0-windows\platform-tools> adb pair
adb: usage: unknown command pair
```

Tried downloading fresh again, and still the same error. Do I need to install other packages aswell? I just want the command line tools.

Comment: Make sure the running adb server is also from the downloaded framework (it stays resident once started). so execute `adb kill-server` to stop it. Next time you use adb it will be restarted using the adb version you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using an ADB version I didn't know was installed. Opening PowerShell directly in the folder and running

```
./adb
```

Made it work, just fine.